How to implement custom ConstraintValidatorFactory?
I am trying to perform custom object validation programmatically using Validator interface. Here is a simple example,

Model Class (Record)

public record Product(String name, int price) implements Serializable {}


Custom Validation Logic: This validates if the product price is positive

public class PositivePriceValidator implements Predicate<Product> {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Product product) {
        return product.price() > 0;
    }
}


Now I am trying to programmatically register the PositivePriceValidator during ValidatorFactory creation. I am using Hibernate Validator as Bean Validation provider,

class MyConstraintValidatorFactory implements ConstraintValidatorFactory {

    @Override
    public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> constraintType) {
        if(constraintType.equals(PositivePriceValidator.class)) {
            return (T) new PositivePriceValidator();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
    }
}


Finally here is my test,
    @Test
    public void testInvalidProduct() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
                .configure()
                .constraintValidatorFactory(new MyConstraintValidatorFactory())
                .buildValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Product invalidProduct = new Product("Hat", -5);

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Product>> violations = validator.validate(invalidProduct);
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }

The above test fails - org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <0>
Can someone help me in understanding what wrong with this code? I am using this as a reference -https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=8.0#example-using-custom-constraint-validator-factory
Note: I know I can directly add @Positive annotation here in this case, but above is just an example. I would like to utilise this approach wherever I cannot apply default or custom BV annotations.

Normally I think you need something like this decorating your Interface
@Constraint(validatedBy = PositivePriceValidator.class)
public @interface PositivePrice {
    String message() default "Price must be greater than 0";
}


As I mentioned I do not want to create custom BV annotations.
